# How to join different line segments between points into one entity in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile of pipe lines. I want to join all the pipes between two valves to be considered as one segment in QGIS.

Comment: If you don't want to draw it by hand consider providing a bit more information on the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

If your lines share a common node you can do as follows. First, load the layer, and set it to be in editing mode. Now

1) Select the features you want to join (this is mandatory). Since you want to select more than one feature, do not forget to use the ctrl key while selecting features.

2) Look in the digitizing toolbar for an icon looking like a cloud with a star. This one is the "merge selected features" tool. The dialog box is easy to follow.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Gerardo but there are like a thousand valves so it's not possible to do manually. I am looking for something in which I can select many segments at the same time and it merges the lines while respecting the valves as separation points.               Thanks in advance